# Vulnerable Java applications?

Tags: java, known-vulnerabilities

I am looking for some open source/free vulnerable Java based applications. It can be web application, desktop application or any other. I need them to do some experiments in my research work. They could be very small or medium size but it's nice if it is like real world application.

The vulnerabilities may include XSS attacks, accessing unauthorized data, SQL-injection etc.

I already tried OWASP applications but need some more. Could somebody please suggest where can I find such vulnerable/exploitable Java applications?

Comment: Can't you just create your own?

Comment: @Ramhound:- I want to try different vulnerabilities so it is really time taking to create an application for each scenario..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are new to hunting I recommend starting out with [WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WebGoat_Installation) or Damn Vulnerable WebApp (DVWA).  This is because it frames each vulnerability nicely,  you just have to point and shoot.  You can practice exploitation, and working with a real vulnerability. "The shooting range"

There are real applications that where intentionally written to be insecure (Like the [Hacme series](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/index.aspx), which is under SASS Tools).  [The Dojo](http://www.mavensecurity.com/web_security_dojo/) has a collection of these apps loaded onto a VM as well as tools to audit them.  This is really the 2nd step because now you have to find where to shoot. "Hunting on the farm"

The 3rd step is going out and finding a real application.  Search github/sourceforge/bitbucket/ect for web applications that are less than a year old and aren't that popular.   These apps will vary,  but most often then will be very insecure. "Hunting in the wild"

After that start working your way up to more popular applications,  get CVE numbers,  write exploit code, and explore newly developed exploitation techniques: exploit-db.com .  "It gets more wild..."

Comment: To be clear - the assumption is that if you're 'hunting in the wild', the 'preserve' is on a machine **you have legal access to**.  If you start finding vulnerabilities for opensource projects by hunting in somebody else's preserve (that is, against a machine you don't have the legal right to access), the have every right to report you.  Permission in writing is otherwise required.

Comment: @X-Zero  i don't see how this applies to my post.  Performing a backbox analysis of a publicly available applications is inefficient to say the least.

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear that, when you run against a 'live' instance to confirm the vulnerability, you need to run against something you have legal access to.  You can't just run against somebody _else's_ instance - you need legally verifiable permission.

Comment: DVWA is a PHP application. The OP asked for a Java app.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at SpringMVC jPetStore it has a number of nice vulnerabilities.

See [this link](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/category/java/spring-mvc/jpetstore/) for detailS, examples, code samples and fixes

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Stanford SecuriBench](http://suif.stanford.edu/~livshits/securibench/).  It is a collection of open-source Java web applications that have had a variety of vulnerabilities, and which were used in some previous research papers to evaluate research tools.  The collection is old (2005?) but it might still be useful for your purposes.

The benchmark includes both artificial applications that were designed to showcase some vulnerabilities (like WebGoat), as well as some realistic applications that were taken from real life and are not artificial.  I think the latter is probably more useful for evaluation of tools, as they are more likely to be representative of coding patterns in real applications.